# Set a fullcalendar with meteor.js

Tags: javascript, meteor, fullcalendar

i am new to meteor, and i am trying to set a full calendar. i am using windows, and i did the `meteor add fullcalendar:fullcalendar` but I can't render the fullcalendar... i have read so many tutorials so far but still nothing. here is a sample of the code that im using. 
I dont know if there is a way to check if the fullcalendar package did install in my app... or if I have to import it...

main.js

```
import { Template } from 'meteor/templating';
import { Notes } from '../lib/collections.js';
//import { fullCalendar} from 'fullcalendar';
//import { moment } from 'moment';


import './main.html';

Template.body.helpers({
 /*
  notes:[
    {text: 'My note 1'},
    {text: 'My note 2'},
    {text: 'My note 3'}
  ]
  */

  notes(){
    return Notes.find({});
  }
});


Template.add.events({
  'submit .add-form': function(){
    event.preventDefault();

    //get input value
    const target = event.target;
    const text = target.text.value;

    //insert note into collection
    Notes.insert({
      text,
      createdAt: new Date()
    });

    //clear the form
    target.text.value = '';

    //close the modal
    $('#modal1').modal('close');

    return false;
  }
});

Template.note.events({
 'click .delete-note': function(){
   Notes.remove(this._id);
   return false;
 }
});

Template.calendar.onRendered()({
 $('#calendario').fullCalendar();
})
```

main.html

```
<head>
  <title>note manager</title>
   <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<nav class="red">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Danillo</a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="waves-effect waves-light btn modal-trigger" href="#modal1"> ADD Modal</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  <div class="container">
      <h1>Nomes</h1>
      <ul class="collection">
      {{#each notes}}
      {{> note}}
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>


  {{>add}}

  {{>calendar}}



  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
          // the "href" attribute of the modal trigger must specify the modal ID that wants to be triggered
          $('.modal').modal();
        });
        </script>

</body>

<template name="note">
  <li class="collection-item">
    {{text}}
    <a href="#" class="delete-note secondary-content"><i class="material-icons">close</i></a>
  </li>
</template>

<template name="add">
    <div id="modal1" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
         <h3>Add Nome</h3>
         <form class="add-form">
           <input type="text" name="text" placeholder="Add Nome...">
         </form>
        </div>
      </div>

</template>

<template name ="calendar">
  <div class="container">
    <div id="calendario">
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

thanks guys!

Comment: Any errors / warnings in your browser's developer console? That HTML page doesn't seem to contain any reference to loading the fullCalendar files, nor the momentJS files which would also be required. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/ . I don't know how meteor works, but would the lines you've commented out entitled "import moment" and "import fullcalndar" need to be un-commented, do you think?

Comment: Hey man....thanks for the answer... I just got it working...have been revising it for the last 4 hours...now my problem is with events... I will create another topic...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Inside

```
Template.TemplateName.rendered = function()
```

function you have to define all the things likes.eg-: eventRender,dayClick,eventAfterRender,viewRender,eventClick etc

sample code that I used inside Template.TemplateName.rendered = function()

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    //height: "auto",
    minTime: OpenTime,
    maxTime: closeTime,
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    timezone: "Asia/Colombo",
    allDaySlot:false,
    dayOfMonthFormat: 'ddd - DD MMM',

    defaultView: 'multiColAgendaDay',
    views: {
        multiColAgendaDay: {
            // disabledColumns: [1],
            type: 'multiColAgenda',
            duration: { days: 1 },
            numColumns: 7,
            columnHeaders: stylistDetails,
            /* disabledColumns: [1] */
        }
    },
    scrollTime: '09:00:00',
    allDaySlot: false,
   /* header: {
   left: 'multiColAgendaDay',
   center: 'title',
   right: 'today prev,next'
   }, */

  header:false, 
  dayOfMonthFormat: 'ddd - DD MMM',

  events( start, end, timezone, callback ) {
let filterBranchId = Session.get("filterBranchId");

let data = AppointmentsServices.find({branchId:filterBranchId,stylistDisabled: {$ne: true}}).fetch().map( ( event ) => {

return event;
});
```